# How to copy a whole text file into a char array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, file, borland-c++

```
int main()
{
char ch;
char text[500];
char s[500];

ifstream fin("bitch.txt",ios::in);
while(!fin.eof())
{
fin.getline(s,500);
}
fin.close();

for (int i=0; i<500; i++)
{
   cout << s[i];
}
return 0;
}
```

How to copy a whole text file contents into a char array in c++ 
considering the text file contains a 100 characters long paragraph
I need to read the spaces too .

Answer (score 3):

Just do this

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <streambuf>

std::ifstream file("file.txt");
std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)),
                 std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Then

```
str.c_str();
```

Is the array that you seek.

Comment: isnt there anything simpler , for primitive compilers

Comment: How primitive do you wish - Got an abacus in the cupboard if you wish to use that

Comment: Why? Download gnu for a start

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the full content of file into the char array, you dont need to do it line by line. You can just copy the full content of file

You can read entire file into the string with

```
std::ifstream in("FileReadExample.cpp");
std::string contents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in)), 
std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

And then you can use contents.c_str() to get char array

Look at the link below. he has given proper answer
[How to copy a .txt file to a char array in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398167/how-to-copy-a-txt-file-to-a-char-array-in-c)

Comment: isnt there any simpler code , 
btw i use borland c++ soo , idk if this will work