# C++ putting text from a file to a char

Tags: c++

So I have multiple words in a text file and I want to put all of them in a char. The problem is that it doesn't keep the space between the words too.
My code:

```
ifstream f("file.txt");
char a[100];
int i=0;
while(f){
f>>a[i];
i++;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how your file.txt structure is?

Comment: And how are you checking the contents of the array?

Comment: well it just has text in it. Let's say for exemple that I have in a file "832 John something" I want to put those words exactly how they are with the spaces between in a char. I'm checking it with a for loop. first with a n=strlen(a), to check the length of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**'>>'** stream operator do not detect space in file. you we have `cin.get(charVariable);` function for it. in your case it will be `f.in(a[i]);`

This will solve your problem;

```
ifstream f("File.txt");
    char a[100];
    int i = 0;
    while (f){
        f.get(a[i]); //use it instead of f>>a[i];
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your'e reading the file word by word. You should use the *std::string contents* function to read the whole text char by char (space char included).

Please read *Nemanja Boric* answer at [This Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398167/how-to-copy-a-txt-file-to-a-char-array-in-c)